# Error: AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'staged_predict'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

Here is the declaration of the estimator:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

param_grid = {'learning_rate': [0.1],
              'max_depth': [4],
              'min_samples_leaf': [3],
              'max_features': [1.0]
              }
est = GridSearchCV(ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100),
                   param_grid, n_jobs=4, refit=True)

est.fit(X_train, y_train)

best_params = est.best_params_

%%time
est = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=500).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

After running that, when I run the following code I get an error

```
Iterations = 2000
# compute test set deviance
test_score = np.zeros((Iterations,), dtype=np.float64)

for i, y_pred in enumerate(est.staged_predict(X_test)):
    test_score[i] = est.loss_(y_test, y_pred)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-188-bbd634856a9f> in <module>
      9 test_score = np.zeros((Iterations,), dtype=np.float64)
     10 
---> 11 for i, y_pred in enumerate(est.staged_predict(X_test)):
     12     test_score[i] = est.loss_(y_test, y_pred)
     13 

AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'staged_predict'
```

Can anyone provide some insight as to what might be going wrong. I'm pretty sure that staged_predict is still included in the Model_Selection module of scikit learn.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Executing your code is not possible, because "ensemble" as well as the data for "X_train" or "y_train" for instance is undefined. Also GridSearchCV does not contain the method "staged_predict": https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

Comment: @landino just consider different names for GradientBoostingRegressor and GridSearchCV, because the former does has the method staged_predict. The problem is that you have called the two objects with the same variable.